# Switch for cinema program (are you sure option)

Tags: c#

I am writing a cinema program for my college course.
A menu is required (switch statement), I want to implement a "Are you sure option" with "Yes" and "No" options, where the user enters "Y" or "N" at the end of the program before they place the booking. However I am unsure how to add this within my current code.

```
Console.Write("Number of Tickets: "); // Oupts "Number of Tickets" to the console window.
            int numberOfTickets = 0; // Variable for the user to input how many tickets they want and converts it to a int. 
            Booking Booking1; // Variable so Booking1 can be linked to the Booking class to be used for the NumberOfTickets.


            while (numberOfTickets == 0)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfTickets)) // Checks to see if user enters valid character.
                {

                    if (Selection.getSeatsAvailable() > numberOfTickets) // If statement so the program knows if there are enough tickets left.
                    {
                        Booking1 = new Booking(Selection, numberOfTickets); // If enough tickets program will make a new booking (Booking1) which includes the Selection and the NumberOfTickets.
                        Selection.updateSeatsAvailable(numberOfTickets); // Updates how many tickets are available for that showing.
                        Console.Clear(); // Clears the console window.
                        Console.Write(Booking1.toString()); // Outputs the Booking1 variable, including the Film selected and the number of tickets.
                        break; // Stops the program.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Showing Full. Select another showing"); // Outputs "Showing Full" to the console window.
                        numberOfTickets = 1;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please input valid number: ");
                    continue;
                }
        }




        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Hope this make sense and thanks for any help...

Comment: Changing your while loop into a `do{...} while(numberoftickets condition && dudeAccepts);` would be a start. Then you would implement your "are you sure" logic somewhere in between, in order to change the `dudeAccepts` variable accordingly.

Comment: I do see what you guys means however I am very shy and do not talk much due to depression and I do not where else to ask. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You could put another `while` loop around the one checking that tickets have been bought and only exit it if Yes has been entered.

Comment: DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Choose:", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                                {
                                     //do stuf
                                }